# Set default locale on linux server

Tags: linux, settings, localization

How can I change linux default locale, so that all users and applications will have the same locale settings?

Br, Wolfy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Ubuntu edit

`/etc/default/locale`

For Centos edit

`/etc/sysconfig/i18n`